# project euler task 23

Tags: math, perfect-numbers

I don't get the part of the task:

> A perfect number is a number for which the sum of its proper divisors is exactly equal to the number. For example, the sum of the proper divisors of 28 would be 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28, which means that 28 is a perfect number.

A number n is called deficient if the sum of its proper divisors is less than n and it is called abundant if this sum exceeds n.

As 12 is the smallest abundant number, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16, the smallest number that can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers is 24. By mathematical analysis, it can be shown that all integers greater than 28123 can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers. However, this upper limit cannot be reduced any further by analysis even though it is known that the greatest number that cannot be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers is less than this limit.

Find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers.

Don't get this:

> However, this upper limit cannot be reduced any further by analysis even though it is known that the greatest number that cannot be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers is less than this limit.

Why don't just tell that the greatest number that can't be expressed is 28123, since if it's smaller, the limit can't be reduced? Or i'm wrong somewhere and the greatest number is different??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence means that it could be possible that 28123 can be represented as the sum of two abundant numbers. We know that any number greater than 28123 can be represented in such a way, but we know nothing about numbers up to 28123 - you have to check them one by one.